# Positioning JLabel on JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

```
public class Test extends JFrame {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JLabel label = new JLabel("g");
    JLabel label2 = new JLabel("w");

    public Test(){
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH));
        this.setSize(200,200);
        panel.add(label, new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT);
        panel.add(label2, new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT);
    }
}
```

I thought this would put the label to the right of label2 but doesn't how would I go about doing this ?

Answer (score 0):

Problem in next `panel.add(label, new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));` is false construction, your `JPanel` as default has `FlowLayout` and you add components from left to right or from right to left one by one. Because of that add your labels like next:

```
 panel.add(label2);
 panel.add(label);
```

Also:

Call `setVisible(true);` at the end of the construction of `JFrame`.

Use `pack()` method instead of `setSize(200,200);`

Read tutorial for [`LayoutManagers`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html) and [`FlowLayout`.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/flow.html)

Comment: OK but if I want the JLabel to be the furthest to the right that it can be, how could I do that ?

Comment: You can use next [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/FlowLayout.html#FlowLayout(int,%20int,%20int)) for adding gaps to components, or another LayoutManager, for example [`GridBagLayout`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html).